# Displaying form results with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I got a form, with 4 questions (1 question has 4 radio buttons), each question is stored inside a div.

With jquery i first show the 1st div, when i press the next button i show the 2nd, and so on.

Heres the entire code for it:

```
    <form style="position:absolute; margin-left:140px;" method="post">
        <div id="question1">
            Q1
            <br/>
            <input name="q1" type="radio" value="q1a1">
            A1
            <br/>       
            <input name="q1" type="radio" value="q1a2">
            A2      
            <br/>
            <input name="q1" type="radio" value="q1a3"> 
            A3  
            <br/>
            <input name="q1" type="radio" value="q1a4"> 
            A4
            <br/>
        </div>

        <div id="question2">
            Q2
            <br/>
            <input name="q2" type="radio" value="q2a1">
            A1
            <br/>       
            <input name="q2" type="radio" value="q2a2">
            A2      
            <br/>
            <input name="q2" type="radio" value="q2a3"> 
            A3  
            <br/>
            <input name="q2" type="radio" value="q2a4"> 
            A4
            <br/>
        </div>

        <div id="question3">
            Q3
            <br/>
            <input name="q3" type="radio" value="q3a1">
            A1
            <br/>       
            <input name="q3" type="radio" value="q3a2">
            A2      
            <br/>
            <input name="q3" type="radio" value="q3a3"> 
            A3  
            <br/>
            <input name="q3" type="radio" value="q3a4"> 
            A4
            <br/>
        </div>

        <div id="question4">
            Q4
            <br/>
            <input name="q4" type="radio" value="q4a1">
            A1
            <br/>       
            <input name="q4" type="radio" value="q4a2">
            A2      
            <br/>
            <input name="q4" type="radio" value="q4a3"> 
            A3  
            <br/>
            <input name="q4" type="radio" value="q4a4"> 
            A4
            <br/>
        </div>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <input type="button" id="submit" name="Submit" />
    </form>
<button id="next">Next question</button>
<script>
$('#submit').hide();
$('div[id^="question"]').hide().first().show();
    $("#next").click(function (e) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('div[id^="question"]:visible').hide().next().show();
    });
</script>
```

This is what i want - when the last (4th) question loads, i want my `next` button to change into submit button. When i press the submit button it would show witch radio buttons were selected. Any suggestions on how can i do this?

Comment: This will fail if client has turned off JavaScript

Comment: you can take the count of the radio buttons and then if count equals then you can show submit button.. have to use click count to do the logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var currentQuestion = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.next').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(currentQuestion < 4) {
            $('#question' + (currentQuestion).toString()).hide();
            $('#question' + (currentQuestion + 1).toString()).show();
            currentQuestion++;
        }
        else { // On question four, process the form
            // Not sure what you want to do with the data, but 
            // you can parse them like this:
            var selections = {};
            for(var i=1;i<=4;i++) {
                selections[i] = $('input[name="q' + i.toString() + '"]:checked').val()
            }

            // Then you have a JS object with your questions and 
            // corresponding choices, so you can do what you want.
        }
   });
});
```